# ubuntu, how to make .git files available from terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I am new to ubuntu and ssh, I am trying to pull changes to a git repo via ssh connection, the repo was dumbed as is from a different machine, the problem now is when I try to use any git command, I get

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

using the `ls` command, doesn't show the .git files, 
using the `ls --all` does show them, so I think they are hidden or not accessible somehow.
so how to make them accessible so I can manipulate the repo using git commands

Comment: Any file/directory which name starts with a dot is "hiddent" in Unix and requires `ls -a` to be seen. But that "hiddennes" from `ls` doesn't prevent them to be used with `git`. Your question doesn't provide enough info. We need to see paths and directories contents. Use `pwd` and `tree`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find the `.git` directory with this command

```sh
find -name .git
```

This will search recursively from the current directory a directory named `.git`

`cd` in the repo directory before issuing Git commands.

If you cannot find the repo, you should clone it again.